# Handlebars Template is not rendered

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Hey I am completly new to Handlebars.js and almost new to JavaScript itself.
So I tried to go through the following tut: http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/

I completed Part 5 and wanted to test the app in the browser. But the page ist blank. Does the browser recognize handlebars.js by himself and renders the handlebars template automatically? Or why do I receive a blank page?

I hope the questions is not to basic, however I have no clue how to proceed or where my error lies.
index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script id="home-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class='header'><h1>Home</h1></div>
        <div class='search-bar'><input class='search-key' type="text"/></div>
        <ul class='employee-list'></ul>
    </script>



    <script id="employee-li-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#.}}
        <li><a href="#employees/{{this.id}}">{{this.firstName}} {{this.lastName}}<br/>{{this.title}}</a></li>
        {{/.}}
    </script>


    <script src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/storage/memory-store.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/handlebars.js"></script>

</body>
```

main.js:

```
var app = {

findByName: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.store.findByName($('.search-key').val(), function(employees) {
        $('.employee-list').html(self.employeeLiTpl(employees));
    });
},

initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.store = new MemoryStore(function() {
        self.renderHomeView();
    });
    this.homeTpl = Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html());
    this.employeeLiTpl = Handlebars.compile($("#employee-li-tpl").html());
},

renderHomeView: function() {
    $('body').html(this.homeTpl());
    $('.search-key').on('keyup', $.proxy(this.findByName, this));
},

showAlert: function (message, title) {
    if (navigator.notification) {
        navigator.notification.alert(message, null, title, 'OK');
    } else {
        alert(title ? (title + ": " + message) : message);
    }
},
```

};

app.initialize();

I get the follwoing errors in main.js:
ln. 15: Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined 
ln 20. :Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'homeTpl'

Kind regards,
Snafu

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I am editing it in the text editor notepad++....do I have to build it somehow? I thought the browser would handle the script with a javascript intepreter or something like that?

Comment: :) Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Posting your code is always helpful.

Comment: I included the code and the error messages in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `handlebars.js` above your `main.js` script tags.

Comment: so as main.js needs every .js it has to be the last one?

Comment: In this instance, your main.js is trying to use a handlebar method/object that doesn't exist yet, because it gets included/executed after you main.js script tag. Most browsers fire off these requests async so load time per file can vary, this is why people wait for document load before executing code.

Answer (score 0):

I did the above change...which seemed quite logical. However, the above solution didn't work.

I added the below

```
this.homeTpl = Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html());
this.employeeLiTpl = Handlebars.compile($("#employee-li-tpl").html());
```

in the renderHomeView function... Works well for me..... :)

```
renderHomeView: function()  {       
    this.homeTpl = Handlebars.compile($("#home-tpl").html());
    this.employeeLiTpl = Handlebars.compile($("#employee-li-tpl").html());
    $('body').html  ( this.homeTpl());
    $('.search-key').on('keyup', $.proxy(this.findByName, this));   
}
```